# Positioning two elements on opposite ends of a 100% with header

Tags: html, css

So css positioning is a subject with a million questions on stackoverflow and tutorials on the internet. Yet, I keep finding myself coming back to research this topic, mainly because it bothers me and I can never find a solution to my specific topic.

To make it simple, I have a 100% width div tag as a header, like so.

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100px;">

</div>
```

Now, on the left side of the screen inside of this div, I have 4 links wrapped in a container div. On the right side of the screen I have two links, wrapped in a container div. Both of these container divs have set widths. Everything else in the middle is empty space.

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100px;">

<div style="width: 400px">
<div style="float: left; margin-left: 5px;">link1</div>
<div style="float: left; margin-left: 5px;">link2</div>
<div style="float: left; margin-left: 5px;">link3</div>
<div style="float: left; margin-left: 5px;">link4</div>
</div>

<div style="width: 200px">
<div style="float: left; margin-left: 5px;">link1</div>
<div style="float: left; margin-left: 5px;">link2</div>
</div>

</div>
```

The question is, I want these two fixed-sized container divs to sit on opposite ends of the fluid sized 100% container they are in. When the browser is resized and shrunk, I don't want to have the right fixed container (1) drop below the left or (2) overlap the left, and I also don't want to see a scrollbar (aka use overflow) or use a javascript fix.

Is there no way to just have the two fixed-sized container divs run into each other and stay in that position as the page continues to shrink?

Floats won't do it, I can't get dislay: inline-block to work in this scenario. Can't do a large fixed size container div because I want the width to be 100%. My current fix is using Javascript to hide the right links when the page shrinks to a certain size, but I don't like doing this.

Is there really no way around this in this situation?

Comment: What do you expect to happen when the view is resized? Some elements to disappear? To have smaller widths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to set a min-width of 600px in addition to using the width:100% on the container div.
Otherwise the only remaining options are for them to overlap (using position: absolute) or drop below each other (floats alone). Depending on the browser, it'll either stop at your min-width, or at least the right/left links will stay put.

You could also use CSS media queries for showing/hiding elements at various widths if you want.

BTW, better not to use inline styles like this so you can leave things more flexible & easier to update.

```css
.outer {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 600px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #555;
}

.leftLinks {
  width: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  background-color: #999;
}

.rightLinks {
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  float:right;
  background-color: #999;
}

li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">

<div class="leftLinks">
  <ol>
    <li>link1</li>
    <li>link2</li>
    <li>link3</li>
    <li>link4</li>
  </ol>
</div>

<div class="rightLinks">
  <ol>
    <li>link1</li>
    <li>link2</li>
  </ol>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: I only used inline-style for simplicity of posting my problem. But min-width... that makes me feel pretty dumb! Should have thought of that one. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Flexible boxes to the rescue!

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex; /* Magic begins! */
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid red;
}
#left {
  width: 400px; /* Desired width. Will be less is the window is narrow */
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
#right {
  width: 200px;  /* Desired width. Will be less is the window is narrow */
  margin-left: auto; /* Push it to the right */
  border: 3px solid green;
}
#wrapper > div > div { /* Unrelated styles */
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left">
    <div>link1</div>
    <div>link2</div>
    <div>link3</div>
    <div>link4</div>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <div>link1</div>
    <div>link2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good solution - I need to look more into flexbox. Didn't think this was possible w/o percentage widths & he seemed to need specific pixel values. Good tip!